# Слияние блоков при соприкосновении друг с другом

Tags: javascript, css, frontend, css-animation

Пытаюсь сделать эффект слияния блоков при соприкосновении их друг с другом.

Блоки двигаются при ховере мыши, "убегая" от курсора. Делал подобное уже через `move in viewport`, но "динамические границы" ещё не делал.

Вот пример того, как хочу реализовать это (белые круги на фоне) - https://adamnocek.com

Если кто-то сможет подсказать, как реализовать, буду благодарен.

Comment: Включите пример *прямо в вопрос*, к примеру я к нему не могу получить доступ.

Comment: Поменял ссылку на пример